# How to search today only data in Graylog

Tags: graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I found that it's extremely hard to search "today-only" message in Graylog. Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Using `keyword`: `today 00:00:00 +0800 to today 23:59:59 +0800`
2. Using `timestamp:["now/d" to "now+1d/d"]` in query and select `search all messages`

`None of them` is working! :(

Does anyone have a working solution that can save my day? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Keywords are parsed by [Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/doc.jsp). You can use the keyword `today midnight` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wont work. It will still show extra data that's not in the date range

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute time.

Something like:

http://10.10.10.10:9000/search?q=&rangetype=absolute&from=2020-12-23T20%3A31%3A58.620Z&to=2020-12-23T20%3A36%3A58.621Z

Of course, it is much easier if you use the GUI.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I combine this with dashboard?